# If X ~ $P(\lambda )$ $p(2)=2e^{-2}$ , find $P(X>3), E(X) and V(X)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

If X ~$ P(\lambda )$,  $p(2)=2e^{-2}$ , find  $P(X>3), E(X) and V(X)

> I don't understand how to find this things with only p(2)

Comment: What is $P(\lambda)$?

Comment: A Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then its probability mass function, $p$, is given by
$$p(k) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
Knowing that $p(2) = 2e^{-2}$ we have
$$2e^{-2} = p(2) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^2}{2!}$$
and then $\lambda = 2$ (check it). Can you continue from here?

Comment: I think so, knowing that lambda is 2, we can say that E(X) = 2, Var (X) = 2, right? by the definition of expected value of a poison distribution. But I don't understand how to find $P(X>3)$

Comment: That is right. Note that $$P(X>3) = 1-P(X\leq3) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^3 P(X=k).$$